# Another word for shots

Tags: terminology, band

I've been googling for the last 2 minutes and I just can't come up with anything that talks about "shots". Maybe this is a local Toronto term. Here's the definition as I understand it. A shot is when all members of the band accent a particular section note or group of notes. This can be done in unison or not. What is the proper term for this? Yes, I understand that you could call it an accent, but that's not how it would be said if you were playing in a band.

Here's an example (although it's not a super strong example):

(Beyonce - Love On Top @ 1:15)

Comment: I have heart "hits" used in a similar context. In rock its usually a riff.

Comment: Yeah, I've used that too, but I couldn't find anything on that either :(

Comment: "stab" is also related http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orchestra_hit

Comment: Awesome...thanks so much. Perhaps, you should copy your answer in the answer section so I can checkmark your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try "hits". I looked up "orchestra hits" for a more specific answer, as searching Google for just hits in a music context will often lead to "greatest hits."

"Stab" is also related: ["Orchestra hit" on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orchestra_hit)

Comment: I wonder if it's a Euro/US breakdown. 'Stab' is the term I've heard in the UK.